# R: Function that uses variable dataframe names from a vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a number of x dataframes (depending on previous operation). The names of the dataframes are stored in a different vector:

```
  > list.industries
[1] "misc"        "machinery"   "electronics" "drugs"       "chemicals"
```

Now, I want to set every column after the 4th as numeric. As the number of created dataframes and, therefore, the names change, I want to ask, if there is any way to do it automatically.

I tried:

```
for (i in 1:length(list.industries)) {
  paste0(list.industries) <- lapply(paste0(list.industries)[,4:ncol(paste0(list.industries))] , as.numeric)
}
```

Where the function places automatically the name of the dataframe from the vector **list.industries** to set it as numeric.

Is there any way, how I can place the name of a dataframe as a variable from a vector?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mget` to get data as a named list, turn every columns after 4th as numeric and return the dataframe back.

```
new_data <- lapply(mget(list.industries), function(x) {
              x[, 4:ncol(x)] <- lapply(x[, 4:ncol(x)], as.numeric)
              x
             })
```

`new_data` would have list of dataframes, if you want the changes to be reflected in the orignal dataframe use `list2env`.

```
list2env(new_data, .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this fragment (untested):

```
one_df <- function(x) {
    dat <- get(x)
    for (i in seq(4, ncol(dat))) dat[,i] <- as.numeric(dat[,i])
    return(dat)
}
ans <- lapply(list.industries, one_df)
```

So in short: you are looking for `get`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.
I tried it and got the error: " Error in seq.default(4, ncol(x)) : 'to' must have a length of 1". 
The dataframes i want to modify have a dimension of [x,127]. Could it be a problem, that list.industries is a vector?

Comment: There was an error in the code, it should be `ncol(dat)` instead of `ncol(x)`